# Can jAlert lead to any link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am newbie at web developing. I've found this online:

in part of html head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#alert_button").click( function() {
                jAlert('text', 'title');
        }); });
</script>
```

and in part html body:

```
<input id="alert_button" type="button" value="submit"/>
```

I would like that after clicking "OK" in alert box, that refreshes the site. Can that be done? If not, is there any simple way for this to be done?

Thanks on all answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can call location.reload() in the onClose callback, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/#callbacks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#alert_button").click( function() {
            $.fn.jAlert({
                'title': 'onClose Callback',
                'message': 'Check your javascript console!',
                'onClose': function(){
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you on answer, but it did not work. It did not even load the alert window this time.

Comment: Can you add a link to the jAlert documentation that you are using? This was just the main one I found

Comment: I found it on this site http://www.bitrepository.com/stylish-javascript-dialog-boxes.html

I erased everything but the simplest one and it works well, just it stays on the same page with no changing - which I need.

Comment: Hey, I know he wasn't talking about my jAlert plugin, but just wanted to share that I have rebuilt mine and it's worth a glance if either of you get a chance: https://github.com/VersatilityWerks/jAlert